# Create automatically Database table when making a query with Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I've had to do a JavaEE project lately, and it was my first one.
The Java was in MVC and I had to do a website with it.

One mechanism of Java was quite pleasant.
When you called the entity class corresponding to a table, if that table didn't exist, it was created with the fields corresponding to the variables of that class, avoiding errors and making it faster to implement.

I was wondering, out of curiosity, if something similar existed with Zend Framework, and if no, if it was possible to do so in a loosely typed language such as php.

Comment: There's no reason why "loosely typed" languages couldn't do something like this. All you need to do is write enough code to make it happen. I am not aware of any such thing and would also not necessarily advocate it. I'm quite a fan of fine control over my data storage and using migrations to get it up and running.

Comment: That's not built in to Zend Framework, but you may want to look at https://github.com/lex0r/zendscaffolding  It's not exactly what you're talking about, but it might help you build out the functionality yourself. I'll also echo @deceze in that I'm not sure that this is really a great idea. It seems like the kind of lazy development that could turn a simple typo into a major headache.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use it because it's the kind of thing that cause more problems than it solves, but I was just wondering. The loosely typed remark was just because it's easier to attribute a variable type directly to a database variable type than to check the content of every variable, determine the closest type of variable you'd need and then finally create it.